# Pear tree deficiencies - weak looking growth

Tags: fruit-trees, nutrients, pear

I have never seen this before. Tree looks weak, the only thing that had changed this year was few grafts that woke up early on in the season and grew vigorously. Could they have depleted some resources? (Last photo are the grafts)

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]